# module "android" has no attibute "Android()"

Tags: python-3.x

My python interpreter on my phone says there is no *"attribute"* Android in the android module, which i am able import:

> module 'android' has no attribute 'Android()'

I am pretty sure it's supposed to be a class. I am using android 10 and I have an a71 samsung.

People told me to utilize androidhelper, but I cannot import that.

I did the following:

```py
import android,time

droid = android.Android()

...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
import androidhelper
droid = androidhelper.Android()
```

or

```
import androidhelper as android
droid=android.Android()
```

Comment: as I already said, this doesn't seem to work for me. I am getting following error:
no module named androidhelper
EDIT: do i have to install any module? I already tried do to ```pip install androidhelper ```which didn't work